# Book with teens who have super powers and need to fight membrane like aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, powers

A few years ago I read a book and a bunch of teens gain super powers. They go to this facility to train, I know one becomes super smart with technology and one becomes super strong, and one of the girls can shoot anything she holds at high velocities. Then some of them turn because of the aliens.

It was a decent book when I read it but I forgot the title.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this? Do you recall anything about the cover? And what do you mean by "some of them turn because of the aliens"?

Comment: I don't remember the year, don't remeber the cover, and some of the teens in the group turn against the main character, I believe the aliens took over them but I don't remember, they were a bunch of membrane like aliens.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Dangerous](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20922876-dangerous)*** (2014) by Shannon Hale...?

[image: Front cover of "Dangerous" (2014) by Shannon Hale.]

One [review](https://www.thebooksmugglers.com/2014/06/book-review-dangerous-by-shannon-hale.html) sums the plot of the book up as space camp-turned *Fantastic Four*-turned *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*.

> Certainly, going into the novel, I did NOT get the **space camp-turned Fantastic Four-turned Invasion of the Body Snatchers** kind of vibe. But that’s what *Dangerous* is.

According to the same review, the main character, Maisie Brown, enters a sweepstake to join a prestigious space camp and wins a spot there.

> **Maisie Danger Brown – yes, Danger is her middle name – is a smart, confident young woman who decides to enter a longshot sweepstakes to go to a prestigious astronaut boot camp.** Since she’s not particularly rich or well connected, not to mention that she was born with just one arm, Maisie knows her chances of ever becoming an astronaut (or even getting accepted to camp) are infinitesimal. Imagine her surprise, then, when **Maisie receives the news that she has won one of the coveted space camp spots!**

According to this Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/828857031), at the space camp, Maisie becomes part of a team of five people who are given alien tokens that merge with their bodies and grant them super powers. These powers include supreme technological skills, brute strength and speed, and the ability to shoot small items at lethal speed from your hand.

> **At the space camp, these things called fireteams, made up of 5 people, were created for the sole purpose of finding out who would best use the tokens sent to our planet from the aliens farther out in the galaxy.** The campers know nothing about this hot mess. It just gets better and better. Of course, Maisie's team is picked as the best fireteam and the actual love interest, Jonathan Ingalls Wilder (I told you it gets better. His out-of-the-picture mom had an obsession with Little House on the Prairie.) is thrown in as a 6th team member. **The fireteam is then sent into outer space and given these tokens that merge into their body and partially stick out of their chest. Oh, and they also give them superpowers: supreme technological skills, cognition abilities beyond compare, brute strength and speed, the ability to create a shield around your body, and the ability to shoot small items at a terrifying and lethal speed from your hand with a zap of blue light.**

One of Maisie's teammates -- a boy named Wilder -- betrays and kills some of the others in order to get their tokens and powers.

> When the team member with the brute token dies, the one with the thinker token is supposed to take it and use it, but our favorite heroine takes it by accident and loses the tech token and instead gains the brute token. The fireteam then splits up for silly reasons. **Wilder, the love interest, apparently was out to get all of the tokens in the first place (And through that, effectively killing all of the other members of the team since they can't be removed without stopping one's heart.) and ended up chasing after Maisie to use her to help him get the tokens without telling her.** When that fails, he tries to off himself and is dead for a few moments, wherein Maisie takes the tinker token and the blue shot token (Wilder already had killed for that one.) and then, surprise surprise, comes back to life.

Eventually though, Maisie ends up with all five tokens and uses them to defeat pink floating aliens that came to Earth to possess people's bodies.

> **Maisie ends up gaining all of the tokens through a series of unfortunate events and realizes that she has a purpose: to defeat the pink floating aliens that are coming to Earth to possess our bodies and experience adrenaline and food through us.** She, again, gets shot into space and has to destroy their spaceship which seems to closely resemble a candy bar, seeing as how the aliens love food and can only move through solid material. She THEN proceeds to FALL FROM THE EDGE OF OUTER SPACE AND SURVIVE, despite the fact that she lost all 5 tokens in the effort to destroy the mothership.

According to another [review](https://writingya.blogspot.com/2014/06/turning-pages-dangerous-by-shannon-hale.html), one of Maisie's other teammates, Mi-sun, is an Asian girl who drinks nothing but blue slushies.

> Mi-sun, an eleven-year-old Asian girl, who drinks nothing but blue slushies

Another [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/672577459) indicates that Mi-sun is the one who initially had the blue shot token that let her shoot objects from her hand, while Maisie started off with the techno token that enabled her to understand and build technology.

> While in space these five kids get to see alien artifacts and wind up absorbing their powers. Now instead of being human caricatures, they're human caricatures with super powers. Redhead turns into a Juggernaut-esque behemoth and can't stop eating. **Slushie Girl can shoot things from her palms. Maisie discovers an ability to understand technology and build.**

Comment: That's it thank you.

Comment: @user171431 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.